# Как удалить combobox из ячейки таблицы.Модуль PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, combobox, pyqt

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
    self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    self.table.setColumnCount(3)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
    data1 = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
    data2 = ['1','2.0','3.00000001','3.9999999']
    combo_box_options = ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"]

    self.table.setRowCount(4)

    for index in range(4):
        item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
        self.table.setItem(index,0,item1)
        item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
        self.table.setItem(index,1,item2)
        #Creat combobox

        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        for t in combo_box_options:
            combo.addItem(t)
            pass
        self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,combo)
        pass
    return
```

Comment: А метод QTableWidget.removeCellWidget - не подходит? Нужно знать адрес ячейки.

Comment: Благодарю. Работает -  self.table.removeCellWidget (i,j), где i,j строка и столбец.

Comment: Как мне указать что ваш ответ верный?

Comment: Динамически это сделать не получилось

Comment: А что значит динамически? Вы по нажатию кнопки удаляете?

Answer (score 0):

У виджета `QTableWidget` есть метод `removeCellWidget(row, column)`, который позволяет удалить виджет из указанной ячейки.

Пример использования на основе вашего кода:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt


class Window(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        data1 = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4']
        data2 = ['1', '2.0', '3.00000001', '3.9999999']
        combo_box_options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for index in range(4):
            item1 = Qt.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
            self.table.setItem(index, 0, item1)
            item2 = Qt.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
            self.table.setItem(index, 1, item2)
            # Creat combobox

            combo = Qt.QComboBox()
            for t in combo_box_options:
                combo.addItem(t)
                pass
            self.table.setCellWidget(index, 2, combo)
            pass
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        button = Qt.QPushButton("removeCellWidgets")
        button.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        layout.addWidget(button)

    def remove(self):
        print("Remove widgets")
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            w = self.table.cellWidget(i, 2)
            text = w.currentText()
            self.table.removeCellWidget(i, 2)
            new_item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem(text)
            self.table.setItem(i, 2, new_item)
        self.table.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

При нажатии кнопки все ComboBox'ы будут удалены, а в ячейки будет вставлен последний выбранный текст из них.

Comment: а как удалить QTableWidgetItem()?